# Solved problem of a three state Markov chain conditioned on two states

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

Given a Markov chain with three states, $J = \{1,2,3\}$, and a transition matrix
$$P = \begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & 1/4 & 1/4 \\ 1/3 & 0 & 2/3 \\ 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

If we know that $$P(X_1 = 1 ) = P(X_1 = 2) = 1/4$$
Find $$P(X_1 = 3, X_2 = 2, X_3 = 1)$$

For a joint Markov chain for example, this could have been \begin{align*}P(X_1 = 3, X_2 = 2, X_3 = 1 ) & = P(i_3) \cdot P(i_3, i_2) \cdot P(i_2, i_1) \\ & = (?) \times (1/2) \times (1/3) \end{align*}

But here is the case that we have a three state Markov chain conditioned on two states. Is there a general theorem or whatsoever to tackle this kind of problems? I would be glad to know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the definition of conditional probability (conditioning on the event $\{X_1=3\}\cap \{ X_2 = 2\}= \{X_1=3,X_2=2\}$), we get $$P(X_1=3,X_2=2,X_3=1)=P(X_3=1|X_2=2,X_1=3)\cdot P(X_2=2,X_1=3)$$
Using Markov property, since the state of $X_3$ depends only on the state of $X_2$, hence independent of $X_1$, the right side above can be modified as $$P(X_1=3,X_2=2,X_3=1)=P(X_3=1|X_2=2)\cdot P(X_2=2,X_1=3) \\  = \frac13 \cdot P(X_2=2,X_1=3) \\(\text{using conditional probability   }) \ \ = \frac13 \cdot P(X_2=2|X_1=3)\cdot P(X_1=3) \\ (\because \{1,2,3\} \text{ are the only possible states})\  = \frac13 \cdot \frac12\cdot (1-P(X_1=1)-P(X_1=2)) \\ = \frac16 \left(1-\frac14-\frac14\right)=\frac1{12}$$

so the term you are looking for is $P(X_1=3)$ which can be determined from the given probabilities of $X_1$ being $1,2$ in the question.

In the context of Markov chains, the probabilities $P(X_1=i)$ for $\{i=1,2,3\}$ in this case determine the [initial distribution of a Markov chain](http://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/stochastik/lehre/ss06/markov/skript_engl/node5.html) (the first state of the random variable is usually referred to as $X_0$ instead of $X_1$).

Comment: You are right. I am trying to link the intuitive meaning of conditional probability to the fact that you conditioned the event $\{X_1 = 3, X_2 = 2\}$ on the joint probability we are looking for. How do I know that we should conditioned on this events in order to arrive at your first line of equation $P(X_1=3,X_2=2,X_3=1)=P(X_3=1|X_2=2,X_1=3)\cdot P(X_2=2,X_1=3)$?

Comment: @holala What is your intuition of a Markov Chain? It's supposed to be a process (a sequence of random variables $X_t$) where the value of $X_t$ is a particular observation from the process at time $T=t$. The time $T$ can be measured in discrete units, i.e. $t\in \{0,1,2,3,\cdots\}$ or continuously, i.e. $t\in \mathbb{R}$. Also, there's the Markov property of the current state depending only on the previous state and no more. What you have in your question is a discrete time Markov Chain. Also, since we have to find the joint distribution $P(X_1=3,X_2=2,X_3=1)=P(A,B,C) \cdots$ (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) $\cdots$ it only makes sense to write $P(A,B,C)=P(C|A,B)P(A,B)$ since we know that we can use $P(C|B)$ from the transition matrix $P$ and in order to abide by the rules of conditional probability, we really don't have much options to arrive at $P(C|B)$ from $P(A,B,C)$ without going through $P(C|A,B)$. I hope we agree that we are using the notation $P(A\cap B)=P(A,B)$ for events $A,B$. 
You can have a look at [sections 11.2.1 - 11.2.3](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter11/11_2_1_introduction.php)

Comment: Absolutely correct @Fawkes4494d3. Going through your solutions, I would have been tempted to say in your seventh line, $ \frac13 \cdot P(X_2=2,X_1=3)  = \frac13 \cdot \frac12 = \frac16$, i.e.by getting $P\{X_2 = 2, X_1 = 3\}$ directly from $P$

Comment: What makes getting this one step probability, $P\{X_2 = 2, X_1 = 3\}$, from $P$ wrong?

Comment: What makes getting this one step probability, $P\{X_2 = 2, X_1 = 3\}$, from $P$ wrong? Could the reason be that $P\{X_2 = 2, X_1 = 3\}$ does not satisfies the Markov chain property and thus we have to "manipulate" it to satisfy the Markov chain property, hence the need of using conditioning on it?

Comment: @holala $P(X_2=2, X_1=3)$ is read as 'the probability that $X_1=3$ *and* $X_2=2$, so it is the joint probability of two steps, not the one step transition probability. The one step transition probability would be "the probability that $X_2=2$ *given* $X_1=3$. It is the same step as from line 1, line 1 has a joint probability written by conditioning as the product of a joint probability and a one-step transition probability. Line 7 is doing the exact step as line 1, writing the joint probability as product of one-step transition probability and initial distribution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111548/discussion-between-fawkes4494d3-and-holala).